# Json formatting from dictionary C#

Tags: c#, json, http, dictionary, json.net

Hello I have a dictionary  that I am using.

```
Dictionary<string, string> myProperties
```

I am trying to format this into a JSON and am having difficulties. I need it to be like this:

```
    {
     "properties": [
      {
        "property": "firstname",
        "value": "John"
      },
      {
        "property": "lastname",
        "value": "Doe"
      },
      {
        "property": "country",
        "value": "united states"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Currently I am using Json.NET to serialize the dictionary but that gives me this:

```
{
  "country": "united states",
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe"
}
```

Can anybody help me format this into what I need. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you paste that desired JSON into your code using Visual Studio's **Edit -> Paste Special - > Paste JSON as Classes** it will create the classes required for that JSON (you'd need a `List<Of Them>`).  Such classes would make your past question much easier too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get there by sending the result from `.Select()` to the json serializer wrapped in a anon class, but I would suggest that you use real classes if you intend to build something larger.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
  new {properties = myProperties.Select(kv => new { property = kv.Key, value = kv.Value})}
  ,Formatting.Indented);
```

This will give you

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "property": "firstname",
      "value": "John"
    },
    {
      "property": "lastname",
      "value": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "property": "country",
      "value": "united states"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Great thank you! Just to get it straight the ToList() method is what formats it in into the "key" "value" for each property?

Comment: yes, I updated the solution with the feedback from @nvoigt to make it all the way as you asked for

Comment: The `ToList()` method will return a `List<KeyValue<string, string>>`  containing the dictionary. This will then be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Building on N0b1ts answer:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { properties = myProperties.Select(kvp => new { property = kvp.Key, value = kvp.Value }).ToList() }, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: No need to use `.ToList()` on an `IEnumerable<TResult>`.